# Exibir produtos recentes cadastrados com php em thumbnails

Tags: php, mysql, crud

tenho uma pagina e preciso exibir na index uns 4 thumbs com os produtos mais recentes cadastrados no meu Banco mysql, quero fazer isso usando php. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço. Minha index usa bootstrap 3.

Comment: Faz uma consulta no banco utilizando "ORDER BY data_cadastro DESC LIMIT 4"

Comment: A dúvida é como trazer os dados do banco e/ou como exibi-los na tela?

Comment: Olá Mayron, os usuários não irão colocar data de cadastro, então isso tem de ser gerado automaticamente e inserido no banco.

Comment: @AdemílsonF.Tonato, A duvida é como gerar a data desse cadastro automaticamente para fazer a query e como trazer esse dados até os 4 thumbs que estarão na minha index.html. Obrigado.

Comment: acho que nem vc sabe o que quer :/

Comment: Não é pq a pergunta não esta tão bem explicada que vc pode dizer que eu nem sei o que quero amigo!!!! Alias é meio mania isso por aqui, dizer que a pessoa não sabe o que quer, se falta paciência pra interagir não responda!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O **MySQL** tem uma função que se chama **NOW()** ela retorna a data atual no seguinte formato: '2016-06-30 10:27:34', você pode salvar esse valor no banco de dados em uma coluna chamada **data_cadastro**, por exemplo e usar ela como referência.

Caso queira usar TIMESTAMP, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Imaginando que temos salvo agora nosso campo no banco com a data correta, podemos fazer uma query como sugeriu o *@Mayron Ceccon*:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY data_cadastro DESC LIMIT 4
```

Note que o 4 no final da query diz respeito a quantidade de registros a serem retornados.
Você pode ler mais sobre *LIMIT* na [documentação oficial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) do MySQL ou [nessa bela postagem do Thiago Belem.](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/entendendo-a-paginacao-de-registros-no-mysql)

Para fazer a requisição com jQuery como disse, você pode [ler a documentação do método .ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) no site oficial do jQuery.

E para exibir os dados você precisará fazer um loop no resultado e adicionar seu conteúdo ao:

```
<a href="#" class="thumbnail">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
</a>
```

Feito isso é só mandar o conteúdo para a tela com o próprio jQuery.

**Apenas uma sugestão:** Sua pergunta está totalmente incompreensível!

Comment: Pergunta ou titulo?

Comment: Obrigado amigo, já ajudou bastante!!